# C# searchbox in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, listbox, search-box

I have a problem with searchbox in a C# wpf application project. I want to do a searchbox and I do not know how to get it working.

It should work like this, when I enter something in textbox, it automatically updates the listbox with the word or part of the word I wrote in the textbox.

Here is my code in `MainWindow.xaml`; first is my TextBox where I want to enter a search value I want to see in the listbox

```
<TextBox Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,92,0,0"
        Name="txtNameToSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174"
        TextChanged="txtNameToSearch_TextChanged"/>
```

This is my listbox where I want show the search results:

```
<ListBox Name="BoozeList" ItemsSource="{Binding Boozes}"
             Margin="10,124,0,10"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              Width="233" Background="#FFCFFF90">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Quantity}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UnitPrice}" />

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

This is my code in `MainWindow.xalm.cs`:

```
private void txtNameToSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) //seachbox search fuc from listbox
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Boozename like '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
        dataGridView.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: are txtNameToSearch and txtSearch the same thing?

Comment: @Bijan, yes they are. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

change the row filter string to this:

```
private void txtNameToSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) //seachbox search fuc from listbox
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = $"Column1 like '%{txtSearch.Text}%'";
        dataGridView.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
    }
}
```